# Displaying the 5 rows preceding the row where a field equals a variable

Tags: php, mysql

How can I modify the query below to display the 5 rows in the database preceding the row where `$submission` equals `$row["title"]`?  (When the rows are ordered `points` descending.)

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT title, points, submissionid
             FROM submission 
         ORDER BY points DESC"; 


$result = mysql_query($sqlStr);

$arr = array();

$count=1;

echo "<table class=\"samplesrec\">";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 


    echo '<tr >';

    echo '<td>'.$count++.'.</td>';

    echo '<td class="sitename1">'.$row["title"].'</td>';

    echo '<td class="sitename2"><div class="pointlink2">'.number_format($row["points"]).'</div></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Have you tried just reversing the sort order and limiting to 5, stuff the relevant info into and array, and then loop over that in reverse order?

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing.  Use a where clause to limit the search to only the elements before the one you want to reference by value then reverse order them and use limit to take the first five.

probably easier is to get the result then just do this in php rather than try to do it in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the trick:

```
SELECT title, points, submissionid
FROM   submission s
        ,(SELECT s1.points
          FROM   submission s1
          WHERE  s1.title = $submission
          LIMIT  1) p
WHERE  points > p.points
ORDER  BY points
LIMIT  5
```

If you want the order reversed:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT title, points, submissionid
    FROM   submission s
          ,(SELECT s1.points
            FROM   submission s1
            WHERE  s1.title = $submission
            LIMIT  1) p
    WHERE  points > p.points
    ORDER  BY points
    LIMIT  5) x
ORDER  BY points DESC
```